# How to use GUI Integration with Ubuntu on Windows Community Preview?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xserver

I saw the [announcement](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/announcing-ubuntu-on-windows-community-preview/19789) of a new version of Ubuntu for WSL and decided to [install it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-on-windows-community-preview/9p9q5zh1hrr0?rtc=1&source=lp&activetab=pivot:overviewtab), there is a gui integration option during installation:
[image]

But what does mean "Required Third-party X Server." and "Required PulseAudio for Windows Installed."?
Do i need to install it on Windows or what?
If I need to manually install the X server, rdp and connect, then this could have been done before. What exactly does this option give and how can I install, say GNOME, and run it?

Comment: https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-wsl-oobe/blob/a6105e7348ac77a1c00ae6f56de865b65e54803c/ubuntu_wsl_oobe/ui/views/integration.py#L68 makes it clearer: "Selecting enables automatic DISPLAY environment set-up", i.e, you still need to install an X11 server, but Ubuntu on WSL can try to autodetect the external X11 server.

Comment: @muru that is, I need to install an x-server server on windows, install the environment in the wsl (ubuntu-desktop for example) and will the wsl determine the x-server itself?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be so. You can see exactly what it does in https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-wsl-integration/blob/ac8ad6b20e7263ff5e706e539a3e19e2498135ae/debian/wsl-integration.sh#L43

Comment: @muru is the x410 server suitable for this?